# Text in Notepad++ looks fine, but wraps when printed

Tags: notepad++, printing, tabs

When I complete a form in Notepad++, it looks fine, but is wrapped and skewed in print preview (see photos). It is also skewed when saved to a text file. Word wrap is not selected.
The same thing happens in regular Notepad. What am I doing wrong?

[image: File in Notepad++]

Here is the output if I save it to a text file. Why does it jumble all the text? The same thing happens if I print:

[image: File in Notepad]

Comment: Any chance that your text simply is too wide for the paper you're printing to? You may want to scale down the size in the printing dialog.

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to see the results rather than just the input, but really if you want page layout use an app designed for page layout, not one for plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It would only let me attach one picture and I don't see anyway to add a one to this comment. If you look at my input, the output would take that last figure to the right and bring it all the way back to the left margin creating another line for each entry. I never had any problem before printing from Notepad. If I do a similar input using Microsoft Word, it prints fine. So yes, it may just be a page layout problem.

Comment: Can you post online (Dropbox, OneDrive...) this example text file?

Comment: 1. What character are you using to space items? Tab and Space may behave differently in Print Preview than on screen. Use only spaces. 2. Do you have word-wrap turned on in NPP? Shut it. 3. Look at the saved file in a hex editor, to see what blank space characters are used.

Comment: I used a combination of spaces and tabs to space items. Word wrap is turned off in NPP. I saved the file in a hex editor. Now I fave to figure out how to read it.

Comment: There's no wrapping in your images. But the misalignment is due to the use of tab characters. Don't use it

Answer (score 1):

**To fix this:** in Notepad++ press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole text then select *Edit > Blank Operations > TAB to Space*

It's because the tab character moves the cursor to the next [tab stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) position, which has a width depending on environment. In most code editors it stops at fixed intervals equal to **4 spaces** by default. But plain text editors like Notepad typically use **8-space** tab by default, similar to many terminals

You can clearly see tab differences between Notepad and Notepad++ in the following image where the tab distance gradually reduced until there are 4 characters in Notepad++

[image: Tab difference between Notepad and Notepad++]

That's in the [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) environments, if you use a [proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion) font like the default ones in rich text editors then things are even worse

So by converting all the tabs into spaces the result will now be consistent in any monospaced environments

[image: Notepad++ TAB to Space]

Note that **you shouldn't use tabs at all!!!** The fact that tabs have different interpretations in different environments makes it prohibited or discouraged in modern languages/coding conventions. You should go to *Settings > Preferences > Language* and check **Replace by space**. There you can also set tab size to the desired value. Now you can align the table normally by tab, but spaces will be inserted to the document instead. That's how modern code is typically indented. See [Never use hard tabs](https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/)

[image: Notepad++ tab settings]

Note: Never use a camera to get a screenshot. Use [PrintScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen) (may be printed on your keyboard as PrtScn, PrtScr, PrtSc, PrSc... whatever) instead. Or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to get the current active window. In Windows 10 you can also use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or the built-in [*Snipping tool* and *Snip & Sketch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool) applications